# Spark on EC2, no space left on device

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark

I'm running spark job consuming 50GB+, my guess is that shuffle operations written to disk are causing space to run out.

I'm using the current Spark 1.6.0 EC2 script to build my cluster, close to finishing I get this error:

`16/03/16 22:11:16 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 29948.1 in stage 3.0 (TID 185427, ip-172-31-29-236.ec2.internal): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/spark/spark-86d64093-d1e0-4f51-b5bc-e7eeffa96e82/executor-b13d39ba-0d17-428d-846a-b1b1f69c0eb6/blockmgr-12c0d9df-3654-4ff8-ba16-8ed36ca68612/29/shuffle_1_29948_0.index.3065f0c8-2511-48ab-8bf0-d0f40ab524ba (No space left on device)`

I've tried using various EC2 types, but they all seem to just have the 8GB mounted for / when they start. Doing a `df -h` doesn't show any other storage mounted for `/mnt/spark` so does that mean it's only using the little bit of space left?

My `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  4.1G  3.7G  53% /
devtmpfs         30G   56K   30G   1% /dev
tmpfs            30G     0   30G   0% /dev/shm
```

How do you expand the disk space? I've created my own AMI for this based off the Amazon default Spark one, because of extra packages I need.

Comment: You will need to mount an additional volume, your root volume won't be big enough at a reasonable cost.

Comment: @bmargulies then need a way to mount the "scratch space" at /mnt/spark to those new volumes for all the slaves?

Comment: You could consider 'ephemeral volumes' if it's really scratch space. And use cloud-init to mount them, I suppose.